# No puedo ingresar datos en la base de datos mysql mediante un formulario php

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un formulario de registro de usuario, y al ejecutarlo, me dice que se ha conectado correctamente, y que el usuario se ha registrado, pero al entrar en *mysqladmin*, no hay ningún registro en la base de datos.

Tengo el siguiente código del formulario:

```
<?php
include 'conexiongeografs.php';
$username =$_POST["Nom"];
$apellidos =$_POST["Cognoms"];
$municipi =$_POST["Municipi"];
$comarca =$_POST["Comarca"];
$email =$_POST["Email"];
$ambit =$_POST["ambit professional"];
$especialitzacio =$_POST["especialitzacio"];
$comment =$_POST["comment"];
$insertar = "INSERT INTO jos_users1(Nom,Cognoms,Municipi,Comarca,Email,ambit professional,especialitzacio,comment) VALUES ('$username','$apellidos','$municipi','$comarca','$email','$ambit','$especialitzacio','$comment')";

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$insertar);
if(!$resultado) {
        echo 'usuari registrat correctament';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'error al registrarse ';   
    }


mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Este de la conexión:

```
<?php
$conexion =mysqli_connect("localhost","geografs_geo","geo020908");
if (!$conexion) {
echo 'erroral conectar a la base de datos';
}
else {
echo 'conectado a la base de datos';
}
```

... y por último, el del formulario:

```
<form action="registreobert.php" method="post" role="form">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="username">Nom</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username"
           placeholder="Introdueix el teu nom">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="apellidos">Cognoms</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apellidos"
           placeholder="Introdueix el teu cognom">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="municipi">Municipi</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="municipi"
           placeholder="Introdueix el teu municipi">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="comarca">Comarca</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="comarca"
           placeholder="Introdueix la teva comarca">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email"
           placeholder="Introdueix el teu email">
</div><br>
 <div class="form-group">
<select class="form-control" name="ambit professional" id="ambit">
<option>ÀMBIT PROFESSIONAL</option>
<option>ADMINISTRACIÓ</option>
<option>CONSULTORIA</option>
<option>RECERCA</option>
<option>EDUCACIÓ</option>
<option>ALTRES</option>
</select></div><br>
<div class="form-group">
<select class="form-control" name="especialitzacio" id="especialitzacio">
  <option>ESPECIALITZACIÓ</option>
  <option>PLANIFICACIÓ TERRITORIAL I URBANÍSTICA</option>
  <option>MEDI AMBIENT, PAISATGE, PATRIMONI NATURAL</option>
  <option>TECNOLOGIES DE LA INFORMACIÓ GEOGRÀFICA</option>
  <option>DESENVOLUPAMENT SOCIOECONÒMIC TERRITORIAL, TURISME</option>
  <option>EDUCACIÓ, RECERCA, SOCIETAT DEL CONEIXEMENT</option>
  <option>PREVENCIÓ DE RISCOS</option>
  <option>MOBILITAT I TRANSPORT</option>
</select></div>
<br>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="comment">Altres especialitzacions (especificar):</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="comment"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
</div>
</form>
```

---

pego otra vez los codigos del formulario:

Nom
    


Cognoms
    


Municipi
    


Comarca
    


Email
    

 

ÀMBIT PROFESSIONAL
ADMINISTRACIÓ
CONSULTORIA
RECERCA
EDUCACIÓ
ALTRES



  ESPECIALITZACIÓ
  PLANIFICACIÓ TERRITORIAL I URBANÍSTICA
  MEDI AMBIENT, PAISATGE, PATRIMONI NATURAL
  TECNOLOGIES DE LA INFORMACIÓ GEOGRÀFICA
  DESENVOLUPAMENT SOCIOECONÒMIC TERRITORIAL, TURISME
  EDUCACIÓ, RECERCA, SOCIETAT DEL CONEIXEMENT
  PREVENCIÓ DE RISCOS
  MOBILITAT I TRANSPORT


 
  Altres especialitzacions (especificar):
  


Enviar

el codigo

---

sigue mal os dejo la estructura dela base de datos por si esto fuera el problema

```
id  int(11)         No  Ninguna AUTO_INCREMENT  Cambiar Cambiar Eliminar Eliminar



Primaria Primaria
Único Único
Índice Índice
Más

2   username    varchar(20) utf8_spanish_ci     No  Ninguna     Cambiar Cambiar Eliminar Eliminar   

Primaria Primaria
Único Único
Índice Índice
Más

3   apellidos   varchar(20) utf8_spanish_ci     No  Ninguna     Cambiar Cambiar Eliminar Eliminar   

Primaria Primaria
Único Único
Índice Índice
Más

4   municipi    varchar(30) utf8_spanish_ci     No  Ninguna     Cambiar Cambiar Eliminar Eliminar   

Primaria Primaria
Único Único
Índice Índice
Más

5   comarca varchar(30) utf8_spanish_ci     No  Ninguna     Cambiar Cambiar Eliminar Eliminar   

Primaria Primaria
Único Único
Índice Índice
Más

6   email   varchar(20) utf8_spanish_ci     No  Ninguna     Cambiar Cambiar Eliminar Eliminar   

Primaria Primaria
Único Único
Índice Índice
Más

7   ambit   varchar(60) utf8_spanish_ci     No  Ninguna     Cambiar Cambiar Eliminar Eliminar   

Primaria Primaria
Único Único
Índice Índice
Más

8   especialitzacio varchar(60) utf8_spanish_ci     No  Ninguna     Cambiar Cambiar Eliminar Eliminar   

Primaria Primaria
Único Único
Índice Índice
Más

9   comment text
```

Comment: Que error obtienes al tratar de guardar los datos del formulario?

Comment: ninguno me dice:conectado a la base de datos usuari registrat correctament

Comment: El error puede ser por que no esta colocando nombres a tus inputs, por ejemplo `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Introdueix el teu nom">` no tiene el atributo name, que este caso deberia ser name = nom, ya que lo recibes a traves de post como: $username =$_POST["Nom"]; prueba colocandole los mismos nombres que pones al momento de recibirlos a traves de POST

Comment: `! $resultado`  `!` significa negación , por eso muestra el mensaje como si hubiese agregado el registro a la base de datos cuando en realidad no lo hizo.

Comment: y que tengo que poner en vez del simbolo !?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí te envío corregido el formulario y el *insert*: "Nuevo: Así como esta este código deberías tener todo el formulario."

```
 <form action="aqui va el nombre de la ruta donde esta el codigo del insert" method="POST">
<div class="rows">
    <label for="nom">nom</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nom" placeholder="Introdueix la teva nom">
</div>
<div class="rows">
    <label for="Cognoms">Cognoms</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Cognoms" placeholder="Introdueix la teva Cognoms">
</div>
<div class="rows">
    <label for="Municipi">Municipi</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Municipi" placeholder="Introdueix la teva Municipi">
</div>
<div class="rows">
    <label for="comarca">Comarca</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="comarca" placeholder="Introdueix la teva comarca">
</div>
<div class="rows">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email"  placeholder="Introdueix el teu email">
</div>
<br>
<div class="rows">
  <select class="form-control" name="ambit_professional" id="ambit">
  <option>ÀMBIT PROFESSIONAL</option>
  <option>ADMINISTRACIÓ</option>
  <option>CONSULTORIA</option>
  <option>RECERCA</option>
  <option>EDUCACIÓ</option>
  <option>ALTRES</option>
  </select>
</div>
<br>
<div class="rows">
<select class="form-control" name="especialitzacio" id="especialitzacio">
  <option>ESPECIALITZACIÓ</option>
  <option>PLANIFICACIÓ TERRITORIAL I URBANÍSTICA</option>
  <option>MEDI AMBIENT, PAISATGE, PATRIMONI NATURAL</option>
  <option>TECNOLOGIES DE LA INFORMACIÓ GEOGRÀFICA</option>
  <option>DESENVOLUPAMENT SOCIOECONÒMIC TERRITORIAL, TURISME</option>
  <option>EDUCACIÓ, RECERCA, SOCIETAT DEL CONEIXEMENT</option>
  <option>PREVENCIÓ DE RISCOS</option>
  <option>MOBILITAT I TRANSPORT</option>
</select></div>
<br>
 <div class="rows">
  <label for="comment">Altres especialitzacions (especificar):</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" cols="30" id="comment" name="comment"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="rows">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Al estar usando un formulario sin javascript debe tener el atributo name en todos los `input` que deseas guardar.

En el archivo de ejecución sería así:

```
<?php
include 'conexiongeografs.php';
$username =$_POST["nom"];
$apellidos =$_POST["cognoms"];
$municipi =$_POST["municipi"];
$comarca =$_POST["comarca"];
$email =$_POST["email"];
$ambit =$_POST["ambit"];
$especialitzacio =$_POST["especialitzacio"];
$comment =$_POST["comment"];
$insertar = "INSERT INTO jos_users1(nom,cognoms,municipi,comarca,email,ambit,especialitzacio,comment) VALUES ('$username','$apellidos','$municipi','$comarca','$email','$ambit','$especialitzacio','$comment')";

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$insertar);
if(!$resultado) {
        echo 'usuari registrat correctament';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'error al registrarse ';   
    }


mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Si te fijas en los datos que compartiste del formulario, no están algunos datos que intentas guardar en la tabla, no sé si lo omitiste en el post apropósito o realmente falta agregarlos al formulario,.

Lo otro es que en programación los nombres de variables debe usarlos según las reglas *camelCase* o *underscore*.

Datos de conexión :

```
$conexion =mysqli_connect("localhost","usuario","contraseña",'base_de_datos');
if (!$conexion) {
echo 'erroral conectar a la base de datos';
}
else {
echo 'conectado a la base de datos';
}
```

Comment: se me olvidaba tambien en los nombre de los campos de la base de datos debes usar las mismas reglas debes evitar siempre de utilizar nombres de campos, y etiquetas con espacios en blanco

Comment: Hola he añadido name al formulario y copiado el codigo que me has pasado pero sigue igual no graba ningun registro en la base de datos

Comment: Hola, mira revisando  tu código de conexión veo que  le hace falta el nombre de la base de datos.

Comment: Y que quieres decir y donde concretamente falta este nombre?

Comment: Mira debes mejor enviar el código completo del formulario edita las preguntas agregando lo que hace falta del formulario y los campos de la base de datos también envíalos completos así podremos ayudarte bien. @g

Comment: Ya esta solucionado el problema, tenia el error en los name de l formulario que no coincidian con los de la consulta msqliquery .Gracias a todos

Answer (score 0):

Usa backticks (`) cuando te encuentres con un campo que incluya espacios (en tu caso el campo **ambit professional**)

```
INSERT INTO jos_users1(Nom,Cognoms,Municipi,Comarca,Email,`ambit professional`,especialitzacio,comment) VALUES ('$username','$apellidos','$municipi','$comarca','$email','$ambit','$especialitzacio','$comment')
```

Answer (score 0):

La forma de enviar datos de un FORM (etiqueta html) es mediante los name, cada input debe tener una NAME ASI:

```
<input type="text"  id="username" name="username">
```

Asi le envias el 'username'.

Answer (score 0):

Más cerca aún de la respuesta de @kira es que a todos los campos del formulario les falta el atributo *name* y el valor de ese atributo debe ser el mismo que está usando en la variable post. Como ejemplo:

Campo del formulario:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name=""Nom" id="username"
           placeholder="Introdueix el teu nom">
```

Valor obtenido en el PHP:

```
$username = $_POST["Nom"];
```

De este modo se recibe el valor del campo *Nom*