# Insertar datos desde un formulario a una BD con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, formularios, login

estoy estudiando aprendiendo a hacer un sistema de login, se que esta pregunta está ya muy quemada, he visto bastantes respuestas (que me han ayudado mucho) pero no consigo que se guarden los datos en la BD. He revisado bastante el código, los POST, que todo este bien nombrado... la conexión funciona, y tengo puesto un echo para que avise si guarda o no los datos, pero nunca lo lanza. He basado mucho la estructura en esta respuesta [No puedo ingresar datos en la base de datos mysql mediante un formulario php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/30212/no-puedo-ingresar-datos-en-la-base-de-datos-mysql-mediante-un-formulario-php?rq=1)
A ver si podéis echar un vistazo y decirme que falla.

El formulario:

```
            <form action="envioform.php" method="POST" id="formulario">
            <input type="text" id='nombre' name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" size="53" maxlength="30"><br><br>
            <input type="text" id='apellidos' name="apellidos" placeholder="Apellidos" size="53" maxlength="50"><br><br>
            <input type="email" id='email' name="email" placeholder="Correo electrónico" maxlength="60" size="53"><br><br>
            <input type="text" id='tlf' name="telefono" placeholder="Teléfono" maxlength="15" size="53"><br><br>
            <input type="text" id='fnacimiento' name="fnacimiento" placeholder="Fecha nacimiento (año/mes/día)" size="53" maxlength="20" min="1917-01-01" max="2005-05-19"><br><br>
            <input type="text" id='direccion' name="direccion" placeholder="Dirección" size="53" maxlength="50"><br><br>
            <input type="text" id='sexo' name="sexo" placeholder="Sexo" size="53" maxlength="15"><br><br>

            <h4>Datos de la cuenta</h4>
            <input type="text" id='usuario' name="usuario" placeholder="Nombre de usuario" size="53"><br><br>
            <input type="password" id='contraseña' name="contraseña" placeholder="Contraseña" size="53"><br><br>
            <input type="password" id="checkpass" name="checkpass" placeholder="Confirma tu contraseña" size="53"> <br><br>

            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" required> <span id="disclaimer"> Acepto el tratamiento y gestión de mis datos de acuerdo con la ley orgánica de protección de datos.</span> <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Registrarse" id="btnsubmit"> <br><br><br>
            <p id="texto"></p>
        </form>
```

La conexión:

```
<?php

$conexion = new mysqli('localhost', 'root','','users_web','3307');
$conexion -> set_charset('utf8');

if ($conexion->connect_errno){
    echo "No conectado";

    }else{
        echo "conectado";
}

?>
```

Y el archivo que procesa el registro:

```
<?php
require 'conn_bd.php';

$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$apellidos = $_POST["apellidos"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$tlf = $_POST["telefono"];
$fnacimiento = $_POST["fnacimiento"];
$direccion = $_POST["direccion"];
$sexo = $_POST["sexo"];

$usuario = $_POST["usuario"];
$contraseña = $_POST["contraseña"];
$checkpass = $_POST["checkpass"];

$datos_personales = "INSERT INTO users_data(nombre,apellidos,email,telefono,fecha_nacimiento,direccion,sexo) 
VALUES ('$nombre','$apellidos','$email','$tlf','$fnacimiento','$direccion','$sexo')";
$datos_cuenta = "INSERT INTO users_login(id_user,usuario,contraseña) VALUES('$usuario','$contraseña','$checkpass')";

$insertar = mysqli_query($conexion, $datos_personales);
$insertar2 = mysqli_query($conexion, $datos_cuenta);

if ($insertar) {
    echo 'Datos registrados';
} else {
    echo 'Error al registrar los datos';
}

mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Un saludo!!!

Comment: Puede [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/297988/16597) te sea de ayuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faltan algunos controles en tu código:

1. Recoger las variables directamente podría exponerte a casos de *`Undefined index`*  o de *`Undefined offset`*, considera usar fusión null (PHP 7+) o, en su defecto, operadores ternarios (PHP anterior a 7).
2. Revisa que hubo una inserción **efectivamente**. Revisar el resultado de `query()` no basta. Una consulta se realizará solamente si hubo al menos una fila afectada. Para eso debes usar `affected_rows`.
3. Tu código es altamente vulnerable a ataques de *inyección SQL*. Deberías implementar consultas preparadas para prevenirlo.
4. Evita la mezcla de estilos. Es una mala práctica. Dado que usas el estilo orientado a objetos en la conexión, úsalo en todo tu código. Además, ese estilo es más claro, más limpio y más moderno. Algunas funciones del estilo procedural son obsoletas.
5. No resuelvas los fallos de conexión con un `echo "No conectado";`, por más que el Manual de PHP se empeñe en esa forma que para mi gusto es absurda. Controla el flujo, verificando la conexión en el contexto o, mejor aún, implementa [manejo de Excepciones](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php), para controlar todo dentro de un bloque `try ... catch`.
6. Evita el uso de `ñ` o de acentos en variables, nombres de elementos HTML, nombres de tablas, columnas, etc en la base de datos. Si no hilas fino con la codificación esos elementos podrían romper el código. Podrías adoptar una convención de nombre en inglés, permite variables más concisas, menos verbosas y sería útil en caso de trabajo en equipo.

Vamos a aplicar todo lo dicho en el código.

En el formulario, me permito cambiar `contraseña` por `password`:

```
        <form action="envioform.php" method="POST" id="formulario">
        <input type="text" id='nombre' name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" size="53" maxlength="30"><br><br>
        <input type="text" id='apellidos' name="apellidos" placeholder="Apellidos" size="53" maxlength="50"><br><br>
        <input type="email" id='email' name="email" placeholder="Correo electrónico" maxlength="60" size="53"><br><br>
        <input type="text" id='tlf' name="telefono" placeholder="Teléfono" maxlength="15" size="53"><br><br>
        <input type="text" id='fnacimiento' name="fnacimiento" placeholder="Fecha nacimiento (año/mes/día)" size="53" maxlength="20" min="1917-01-01" max="2005-05-19"><br><br>
        <input type="text" id='direccion' name="direccion" placeholder="Dirección" size="53" maxlength="50"><br><br>
        <input type="text" id='sexo' name="sexo" placeholder="Sexo" size="53" maxlength="15"><br><br>

        <h4>Datos de la cuenta</h4>
        <input type="text" id='usuario' name="usuario" placeholder="Nombre de usuario" size="53"><br><br>
        <input type="password" id='password' name="password" placeholder="Contraseña" size="53"><br><br>
        <input type="password" id="checkpass" name="checkpass" placeholder="Confirma tu contraseña" size="53"> <br><br>

        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" required> <span id="disclaimer"> Acepto el tratamiento y gestión de mis datos de acuerdo con la ley orgánica de protección de datos.</span> <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Registrarse" id="btnsubmit"> <br><br><br>
        <p id="texto"></p>
    </form>
```

En la conexión activaremos el modo de manejo de excepciones y no verificaremos nada más ahí. Lo haremos en el contexto, dentro de un bloque `try ... catch`:

```
<?php
    
    $conexion = new mysqli('localhost', 'root','','users_web','3307');
    $conexion -> set_charset('utf8');
    $driver = new mysqli_driver();
    $driver->report_mode = MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL;    
?>
```

En el contexto, verificamos los `$_POST` con fusión de null, implementamos consultas preparadas y verificamos el insert de la forma adecuada:

```
<?php
    require 'conn_bd.php';
    # Declaramos un array para recoger la info
    $outPut=array();
    # 1º verificamos si hay conexión
    if ($conexion) {
        try 
        {
            $nombre = $_POST["nombre"] ?? "";
            $apellidos = $_POST["apellidos"] ?? "";
            $email = $_POST["email"] ?? "";
            $tlf = $_POST["telefono"] ?? "";
            $fnacimiento = $_POST["fnacimiento"] ?? "";
            $direccion = $_POST["direccion"] ?? "";
            $sexo = $_POST["sexo"] ?? "";
            
            $usuario = $_POST["usuario"] ?? "";
            $password = $_POST["password"] ?? "";
            $checkpass = $_POST["checkpass"] ?? "";
            
            $datos_personales = "INSERT INTO users_data(nombre,apellidos,email,telefono,fecha_nacimiento,direccion,sexo) 
            VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            /*
               Considera cambiar el nombre de la columna 
               contraseña en la tabla para evitar ñ
               cabe decir que el orden es confuso aquí
               ¿El valor de $contraseña es para la columna usuario?
               ¿El valor de $checkpass es para la columna contraseña?
               ¡Cuida el nombrado de tus variables y elementos!
            */          
            $stmt = $conexion->prepare($datos_personales);
            $stmt->bind_param("sssssss", $nombre,$apellidos,$email,$tlf,$fnacimiento,$direccion,$sexo);
            $stmt->execute();
            # Ponemos en $outPut el total de filas insertadas
            $outPut['datos_personales']=$stmt->affected_rows;
            
            $datos_cuenta = "INSERT INTO users_login(id_user,usuario,contraseña) VALUES(?,?,?)";
            
            $stmt = $conexion->prepare($datos_cuenta);
            $stmt->bind_param("sss", $usuario,$password,$checkpass);
            $stmt->execute();
            # Ponemos en $outPut el total de filas insertadas
            $outPut['datos_cuenta']=$stmt->affected_rows;
            
            # Destruimos los objetos
            $stmt=null;
            $conexion=null;
            
            # Esto es una prueba para ver qué pasó con cada insert 
            # Mostrará dos entradas con las filas afectadas
            var_dump($outPut);
            # Si estuvieras en una función
            # Retornamos los datos
            //return $outPut;

        } 
        catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) 
        {
            echo $e->__toString();
            # Si estuvieras en una función
            # Retornamos un array con clave error y el mensaje
            //return array('error'=> $e->__toString());    
            //error_log($e->__toString()); #Opcional
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        # Si no hay conexión
        echo 'No hay conexión a la BD';
        # Si estuvieras en una función
        //return array('error'=> 'No hay conexión a la BD');    
    }
?>
```

Con esto tu problema debería quedar resuelto, y tu código sería seguro. Si tienes dudas pregunta en comentarios, al pie de esta respuesta. **Soy humano, no soy una IA**.

Comment: Hola!! lo primero gracias por tu respuesta y por la explicación, he tenido que repasar algunos métodos y otras cosas que desconocía. Ya he cambiado lo del password y puesto bien la sentencia. Entiendo que los stmt son para seguridad y prevenir las inyecciones es así? y otra cosa sin el método query no estás realizando la consulta realmente, no? He probado el código y no me ha metido nada en la BD, y me ha saltado este error: <br/>

Comment: Warning in .\libraries\classes\Dbal\DbiMysqli.php#209
 mysqli::query(): (HY000/1034): Clave de archivo erronea para la tabla: 'global_priv'; intente repararlo

He probado a hacer como dicen aquí https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/555489/error-base-de-datos-con-xampp-mysqliquery-hy000-1034-clave-de-archivo pero sigo con el error.

Comment: Creo que el problema es que **los datos no llegan a POST**, porque el var_dump del array de envioform.php donde se procesan los datos da error _undefined array key_ he hecho en el formulario un var_dump($_POST) y al dar al submit me sigue mostrando array(0) { }, es como si funcionara el botón y no enviara nada

Comment: ¿Qué código estás implementando para que dé el error *Undefined array key*? Con el formulario que indicas en la pregunta y si implementas el código de la respuesta, eso no debería ocurrir. En cuanto al error `HY000/1034` parece estar en otra tabla. Por lo que puede depender de algún TRIGGER que esté disparando el INSERT actual por ejemplo.

Comment: Perdón por tardar tanto en responder, al final era un error mío, ya lo resolví y el error HY000/1034 también. El problema ahora es que no se porque razón parece que **los datos de los inputs no están guardándose en $_POST, **porque en el formulario hago un _var_dump($_POST) y me da array(0){}_ al pulsar el submit. Le envié a un profesor el código y dijo que funciona bien, hasta me mando una foto de su _var_dump_ y si aparecían los datos en el array. ¿Alguna idea de por qué puede ser? Un saludo!!

Comment: @Bulldops limpia la caché del navegador, o prueba en modo incógnito o cambia temporalmente el nombre del archivo que pones en el `action` del `form`. Si estás poniendo datos no debería salir vacío y si al profesor le funciona bien es un problema no del código, sino de tu entorno de desarrollo. Verifica además que las URL corresponden a los archivos reales y no a archivos erróneos que podrían estar ubicados en otra parte.